# Getting error as: SchoolDetailsView is missing or override SchoolDetailsView.get_queryset, what should I fix in below code?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Model.py

```
class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    principal = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, related_name='students', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views.py

```
class SchoolDetailsView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'school_detail'
    models = models.School
    template_name = 'basic_app/school_details.html'
```

html code code looks like below mentioned in comments

template

```
Name: {{ school_detail.name }} 
Principal: {{ school_detail.principal }} 
Location: {{ school_detail.location }} 
{% for student in school_detail.students.all() %} 
{{ student.name }} who is {{ student.age }} years old. 
{% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
path('', views.SchoolListView.as_view(), name='list'),
path('<int:pk>/', views.SchoolDetailsView.as_view(), name="detail"),
```

Can anyone suggest what am I missing here in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of typo in detail view, should be `model=` instead of `models=`